# How can I stick a div to the bottom of another div?

Tags: css, html, positioning

Okay, so this is the parent div:

```
#left {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #8FD1FE;
    float: left;
    opacity:0.75;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
    -webkit-transition: all .45s ease;  
    -moz-transition: all .45s ease; 
    transition: all .45s ease; }
```

And this is the div inside the div:

```
#reasons {
background-image:url('arrow1.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 94px;
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }
```

I've tried a bunch of different methods, but I can't seem to keep the the second div centered and stuck to the bottom of the first div.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, make the outer `div` a layout parent:

```css
#left {
     /* ... */
     position: relative; /* anything but static */
     /* ... */
}
```

Now let's fix the inner `div` to the bottom:

```css
#reasons {
    /* ... */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /* ... */
}
```

Now it's fixed to the bottom, but we need to center it:

```css
#reasons {
    /* ... */
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -200px; /* 200px is half of the width */
    /* ... */
}
```

**See a demo [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSyMw/).**

Comment: You can also consider using `transform: translateX(-50%)` to center the child div, the benefit of this (if I'm not mistaken) is that you don't need to have a hard-coded width on the child element (400px in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Use    `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`  to keep it to the bottom of a div
and also don't forget to add the second div inside the main div